# How does a ring 3 rootkit manage to modify files in /etc and/or /usr?

Tags: linux, rootkits

A [recent article](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/pokemon-themed-umbreon-linux-rootkit-hits-x86-arm-systems/) spiked my curiosity; please bare with me, I'm no security expert but just a Linux admin.

This states that the rootkit runs from userspace, but modifies `/etc/so.preload` and creates files under `/usr/share`. By which mechanism is this possible?  That the article didn't mention as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just asking how a user-mode program can write files? User-mode (ring 3) does not mean unprivileged, although kernel-mode (ring 0, the opposite of user-mode) does imply privileged. Every time you `sudo` a command, you're running ring 3 code that can modify arbitrary files. The "root" user's programs run in ring 3 just the same as anybody else's.

A rootkit like this obviously requires privileges (i.e. root) in order to install. It does things like create a user, which can be done with userspace code (there are some calls into the kernel, but you don't have to install a kernel module to do it) but cannot be done by an unprivileged user.

As a side note, user-mode rootkits are weaker than kernel-mode ones. As a practical matter, third-party code will essentially never make a system call *directly*, because system calls are not like "normal" functions and the details are platform- and implementation-specific, and might change between major kernel revisions. Making syscalls directly from your code will likely make it non-portable, and is easy to screw up. However, it is *possible*, and if you do that, you will bypass the shim that the user-mode rootkit has set up to tamper with your syscalls.

Comment: Thanks for that, and right, that differentiation makes sense.  I guess what I was hoping to find out is how the privilege escalation takes place.  And how the thing ends up ones machine in the first place.  So my question is incomplete.  Should I reword it?

Comment: @tink That's a pretty different question than you've asked here, but I bet it's been asked before. The malware itself has no privilege escalation, although it may be used as the payload of a privilege escalation bug. It gets on the system the same way as any other malware: either an exploit payload dropped on a vulnerable system (with or without needing a separate privilege escalation step, depending on the vector), or a Trojan Horse installer (which is probably already running as root), or social engineering the user to do something stupid (like `curl <untrusted URL>` piped to `sudo sh`).

Comment: Cheers, that's all I could ask for w/o weeks of reading ;}